# Проблемы с CURL

Tags: php, кодировка, curl

Функция `post` — http://pastebin.com/VhVA7myR

```
$ba_user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36';

$ba_get_main = post('http://www.britishairways.com/travel/home/public/ru_ru', array(
 'headers' => array(
  'User-Agent: '.$ba_user_agent,
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
  'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
  'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch'
 )
));

print_r($ba_get_main);
```

Дело в том, что в [content] возвращаются кракозябры. Но если же убрать `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch'`, то не возвращается ничего.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');` тоже ничем не помогло.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Если 'content' из результата пропустить через функцию gzdecode(),код страницы становится читабельным.

Comment: @Visman, оу, получилось. Превращайте ответ в комментарий. Очень благодарен Вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в [content] возвращаются кракозябры

там возвращается сжатый `gzip`-ом `html`.

либо распаковывайте самостоятельно (например, с помощью [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gzdecode.php)), либо уберите `gzip` из заголовка `accept-encoding`.